# How to find what events cluster together?

Tags: classification, r, clustering, logistic-regression

I have a data set that looks at a five-year timespan of peoples' lives and indicates if specific events have occurred (Divorce, Birth of Child, Health Shock, etc.).

```
# Sample data in R
n <- 100
set.seed(1337)
exampleFrame <- as.data.frame(cbind(1:n,replicate(7, sample(0:1,n, TRUE))))
colnames(exampleFrame) <- c('Person',paste(rep("Event",7),1:7, sep = ''))
```

First thing I did was simply show a correlation matrix.

```
cor(exampleFrame)
```

And it gives an idea of what items follow each other, so next I ran a logistic regression to see how events are likely to improve odds of occurring together.

```
glm(Event1 ~ . - Person,family = binomial(link = 'logit'), data = exampleFrame)
```

And this is interesting, but I feel like I'm missing something more compelling. Am I chasing a phantom? Does anyone know a better way to demonstrate which life events occur together in this five-year span?

Answer (score 1):

It's just a simple idea but you could calculate the conditional probabilities of an event given another:

```
library(plyr)

condProbEvents <- function(d) {
  ldply(colnames(d), function(col1) {
    t(ldply(colnames(d), function(col2) {
      nrow(d[d[,col1] & d[,col2],]) / nrow(d[d[,col2],]) # p(col1|col2)
    }))
  })
}
```

This gives you values which are easy to interpret, e.g. for `p(divorce|marriage)`: "X% of the people who had a marriage also had a divorce"